# Fixing C libraries. Headers reference wrong locations

Tags: c++, c, applet

I have this `applet.c` source file from a project a few years ago. (I am on Ubuntu Mate, 15.10 (FYI).)

Its dependencies are:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>
```

But those headers do not exist. So I did `locate gi18n.h` and `locate glib.h`
which show up:

```
$ locate galloca.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h
$ locate glib.h
...
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h
```

So I change the `applet.c` source code to:

```
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib/gi18n.h>
```

Then when I tried again to compile, `glib.h` threw a fatal error for file not found `/glib/galloca.h`.

Then I realized every header file in all the successive header files are referencing the wrong location inside the `glib-2.0` header files.

For example, `glib.h` refers to `#include <glib/galloca.h>` which exists, but is actually in `#include <glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h>`.

What should I do about this?

UPDATE
$`gcc  -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 applet.c` results in:

```
   glib-2.0 applet.c 
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from applet.c:26:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32:24: fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

which is a significant improvement!

Comment: `gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0` should do the trick. And `#include <glib.h>` should be fine.

Comment: `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0) applet.c -o applet $(pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)` should do the trick.